# Produce a heatmap of Wi-Fi intensity using GPS

Tags: maps, gps, wifi, mapping, radio

There are wardriving apps that will log all APs your phone can see and plot them as points on a map.

[image: wardriving app]

There are "site survey" applications that will make a heatmap of your particular AP, where you give it a blueprint of your building and then manually point out where you are on the blueprint as you walk around:

[image: heatmap of a single AP]

What I would like is an app that logs *all* APs, along with the GPS location of each measurement, and makes a heatmap (such as an overlay on a Google Map) of how strong the average/strongest Wi-Fi activity is at each point on the map, to compare how busy the 2.4 GHz environment is in different places.